# Trying to collect all LTF data into a single array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

just wondering how I could concatenate all of the values from ltf arrays into one single array.  In other words, rather than resetting the ltf array for each new chart bar, I'd like to add to that array so it contains all the ltf data in a single array that updates.

I've tried looping through the ltf array and pushing each value to a new array but it doesnt' seem to add past the index of the max size of ltf values, rather it just resets the loop to index 0 and writes over the previous values.

The purpose of this large array will be to run statistics on the entire population vs. just the current chart bar's

Comment: Use array.join()

Comment: note that array size is max 100k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using an array initialized with `var`. Image below shows my `ltfData` array size, when each bar only has a size of 5.

```
var ltfData = array.new<float>()

ltfC = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid,'78',close)

for c in ltfC
    ltfData.push(c)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high,str.tostring(ltfData.size()))
```

[image: Array size]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.  Could I please ask for a bit of a more technical explanation as to WHY you came to this conclusion; specifically the "for...in..." structure? In my initial research to figure this out I sorta suspected the answer was in some specific syntax of conditionals but obviously was unable to stumble upon the right answer.

Comment: No problem! You could use for in or for i = 0 to array.size()-1, the result will be the same. I just prefer the for in loops. Basically in my example I’m saying for every close in the ltf array for that bar push it into my bigger array

Comment: Huh, I feel like I tried using the counter approach with i=0 to array.size()-1 but maybe I was trying everything except pushing to a new array? Either way, this works and in a totally new way (to me) which is great!  Could I ask for some further explanation on what "c" is in this context.  I understand it's the close from the request.ltf function but it seems weird to me as it's not previously defined?  Sorry if this is an odd question but I'd like to better understand WHY that functions at a technical level within pinescript's compiler so I can apply it in other circumstances! Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, "c" can be anything you want since it is used for the for loop. So in this case I chose "c" for close.  In a loop it just means for each item in the array. Similar to how if you wanted to you could for c = 0 to array.size()-1